# Does C automatically free functions applied to functions?

Tags: c, gcc, matrix, malloc, free

I'm working with matrices in C and looking to improve my code and ensure there are no memory leaks.

My matrix implementation looks like:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int nb_cols;
    int nb_rows;
    float *data;
} matrix;
```

I have a lot of functions that take two matrices as input, and return an output. They look like this:

```cpp
matrix *function(matrix* m1, matrix *m2)
{
    matrix* temp = matrix_init(m1->rows, m1->cols);

    // Doing some stuff 
    // like temp[i * (m1->cols) + j] = m1[ i * (m1->cols + j] + m2[i * (m2->cols + j];
    // (this is just an example)
    
    return temp;
}
```

When I call those functions like this:

```cpp
mat = function1(function2(m1, m2), m3);
```

Does the compiler automatically allows temporary matrices and then frees ? Or should I never do this and have all the temporary matrices to do the operations one by one and free ?

Is writing this any better?:

```cpp
mat_temp = function2(m1, m2);
mat = function1(mat_temp, m3);
free(mat_temp);
```

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Your suggestion is better as the malloc()s are unaware of how "temporary" their usage will be

Comment: "free functions applied to functions" It should probably be to free the output from nested functions. Freeing functions means deallocating the code segments associated with the function, which is probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

2nd is better.

With below, the pointer returned by `function2()` is lost and so the memory allocated to it lacks a corresponding `free()`.  [Memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

```
// lost memory
mat = function1(function2(m1, m2), m3);
```

Instead:

```
matrix *m1 = function0();
matrix *m2 = function0();
matrix *mat_temp = function2(m1, m2);
matrix *mat = function1(mat_temp, m3);
free(mat_temp);
...
free(mat);
free(m2);
free(m1);
```

---

Asides:

> improve my code

If the data pointed to does not change, add `const` to allow for wider function usages and some optimizations.

```
// matrix *function(matrix* m1, matrix *m2)
matrix *function(const matrix* m1, const matrix *m2)
```

If the calling code should *never* provide overlapping data (no surprising data changes), add `restrict` to let the compiler apply more optimizations.

```
// matrix *function(matrix* m1, matrix *m2)
matrix *function(matrix* restrict m1, matrix * restrict m2)
```

... or both `const` and `restrict`.

Good code also tests for failed allocations.

```
if (m == NULL) TBD_code();
```

Comment: Another question: does ```m1 = multiply(m1, m2);``` also causes those memory leaks ? Like returning to itself doesn't free what "was there before" right ?

Comment: @Ouilliam Yes.  Better as `matrix *t = multiply(m1, m2); free(m1); m1 = t;` or code another function: `void multiply_equal(matrix** m1, const matrix* m2);`  and call as `multiply_equal(&m1, m2);` and let it optimally re-allocate `m1` data.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the compiler automatically allows temporary matrices and then frees?

No, the compiler doesn't automatically frees them.

You can allocate some matrix data on the *stack* (using the VLA - variable-length array feature in C99), but if you want to pass it to some other subroutine, you have to use heap (malloc, calloc, realloc, and free, and a few other platform-specific ones)

> Or should I never do this, and use temporary matrices to process operations one after another and then free temporary matrices

If you're unfamiliar with memory management, and is willing to sacrifice efficiency for correctness, allocate-copy-free isn't a bad stratagy.

**But take my words with a grain of salt**, as I've not been programming with memory management for quite some time.

What I've been doing with my recent personal project is that, I allocate all variables statically, by estimating the maximum necessary memory first, then allocate, and never free any of the working context throughout the life time of the program.